# Writing to an MSMQ queue over the network from a local account?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, permissions, user-accounts, msmq

I have this problem which involves writing MSMQ messages from machine A (Windows 7) to machine B (Windows Server 2008) which are in the same network. This problem only occurs when the message is sent from a local account; it works great when sending the message from my domain user account and the local system user (LocalService).

Info and troubleshooting so far:

The dead-letter queue at machine A is filled with messages labeled "Access denied".

The receiving queues on machine B has all permissions granted to the "Everyone" group. This also goes for the overlying security settings of the "Message Queuing" feature. I have also tried granting all permissions to the computer name of machine A.

Events are showing up under machine A's Event Viewer/Applications and Services/Microsoft/Windows/MSMQ/End2End, labeled as "Message came over network". There are, however, no relevant messages shown under Event Viewer/Windows Logs/Application or Security.

The messages sent from machine A and the receiving queues on machine B both have the transactional setting enabled.

I have tried turning off the Windows firewall with no result.

Question:
I suspect that this has something to do with machine B not recognizing the local account used on machine A. 
Is there in some way possible to grant this account the right permission on machine B so that machine A can write to machine B's queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add the permission "Send Message" for the user group "ANONYMOUS LOGON" in the Security settings of the MSMQ queue.

These pages led me to the answer:

[Access To Message Queue System Denied Windows 7 Reading Windows 2003 - Windows 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444121/access-to-message-queue-system-denied-windows-7-reading-windows-2003-windows-2)

[MSMQ 3.0 too secure for you?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/01/15/msmq-3-0-too-secure-for-you.aspx)